# Browser window is bigger than my html/body tag

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

http://lillangshamnens.philipnordstrom.com/

Hello!
I need help because my browser window is bigger than my html/body and because of that i get a scrollbar at the bottom.

Im using wordpress and bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have an iframe element that has a fixed width of 1280px. Try to set the `max-width:100%` property to it. Also the bootstrap *rows* have a negative margin set on them. You may also want to reset that.